# How can I show that the context generated by an operator $A$ is equal to the set of all Borel measurable functions evaluated at $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, spectral-theory, functional-calculus

If we consider that a context is an unital abelian sub-$C^*$-algebra of some unital $C^*$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$, that agree on the unit, then if we define:

> **Definition:** Let $A$ be a unital $∗$-algebra, and $\{A_n\}_{n∈I}$ a collection
> of self-adjoint commuting elements, then there is at least one context containing $\{A_n\}_{n∈I}$, namely the space of all polynomials of $\{A_n\}_{n∈I}$, then we can consider the smallest of all such contexts $\,\bigcap \{C ⊆ \mathscr{A} \,\, | \,\, C \text{ is a context containing } \{A_n\}_{n\in I}\}$,$\,$ and this context is said to be the **context generated** by $\{A_n\}_{n∈I}$, denoted by $\mathcal{C}(\{A_n\}_{n∈I})$.

How could I prove then that for a self-adjoint $A$:
$$\mathcal{C}(\{A\})= \{ f(A) \,\,|\,\, f:\sigma(A) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\,\, \text{ is a Borel measurable function}\}$$

For the special case of matrices I have read a proof using the spectral decomposition of such matrices, realizing that these decompositions are finite and that for $A= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\lambda_iP_i$ each of the $P_i$ must be in the context $\mathcal{C}(\{A\})$, since a context is a unital $*$-sub-algebra, hence:
$$\mathcal{C}(\{A\}) \ni A-\lambda_2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\lambda_iP_i-\lambda_2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n P_i =\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i-\lambda_2)P_i \in \mathcal{C}(\{A\})$$
$$\mathcal{C}(\{A\}) \ni \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i-\lambda_2)P_i-\lambda_3 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i-\lambda_2-\lambda_3)P_i \in \mathcal{C}(\{A\})$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\lambda_1P_1 \in \mathcal{C}(\{A\})$$

Where we can get to each projector $P_i$ because the sum is finite, hence $\{P_i\}_{i=1}^n \subset \mathcal{C}(\{A\})$.
Since $f(A) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n f(\lambda_i)P_i$ by the spectral theorem for matrices, then $\{ f(A) \,\,|\,\, f:\sigma(A) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\,\, \text{ is a Borel measurable function}\} \subseteq \mathcal{C}(\{A\})$, also because of the spectral decomposition theorem for matrices, the elements of $\{ f(A) \,\,|\,\, f:\sigma(A) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\,\, \text{ is a Borel measurable function}\}$ commute two by two, and that set is trivially a unital $*$-sub-algebra, hence a context that contains $A$, hence $\mathcal{C}(\{A\}) \subseteq \{ f(A) \,\,|\,\, f:\sigma(A) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\,\, \text{ is a Borel measurable function}\}$ that then makes $\mathcal{C}(\{A\}) = \{ f(A) \,\,|\,\, f:\sigma(A) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\,\, \text{ is a Borel measurable function}\}$.

But in this proof the fact that the spectral decomposition is finite is fundamental for this proof to work, for a general unital $*$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ this is not true, since the spectral decomposition would be given by $A= \int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda dP^{(A)}(\lambda)$ for a continuous projective valued measure $dP^{(A)}$. Is there a way to prove this whithout using this finite requirement? This theorem is necessary for I to be able to generalise another such theorem that was also proved for matrices in the reference, but that is said to be "easly generalized" for a more general unital $*$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$, this lemma being the only difficulty in my trial to do so.

Comment: Wait, what is clear is that the context generated by a self-adjoint operator is the set of polynomial functions of this operator. Without any closeness requirement on a context, why would you expect to get more than polynomials? Of course, in finite dimension, every Borel function on a finite set (the spectrum) is in fact polynomial.

Comment: Ok, I may have to take the closure on that intersection, this was a slip on my part when adapting this definition for matrices.

Comment: Yes, but « closure » has no sense in an arbitrary involutive algebra.

Comment: @Plop I thought about your question and actually, the base Idea is that the generated context of a family of two-by-two commuting elements is the "smallest" context that contains this family, so by your argument the only thing that I could get is $\mathcal{C}(\{A\}) \subsetneq \{f(A) \,|\, f:\sigma(A) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{ is a Borel measurable function } \}$, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my opinion, the definition you quote is badly written.

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a $*$-algebra. For $S \subset \mathscr{A}$ consisting only of self-adjoint elements that commute one with another, consider the algebra of formal polynomials with one indeterminate $X_s$ for each element $s$ of $S$. Let us denote it by $\mathbb{C}[S]$. Then (exercise) there is a unique $*$-algebra morphism

$eval : \mathbb{C}[S] \rightarrow \mathscr{A}$ sending each $X_s$ to $s$. The image of this map is called the **set of polynomials in $S$** and (exercise) it is the smallest sub-$*$-algebra of $\mathscr{A}$ containing $S$.

Now, turning to your question.

Consider the simple case of $S = \{A\}$, and assume that there exists a finite set $\mathcal{P}$ of mutually commuting self-adjoint idempotents that sum to the identity and a family $(\lambda_P)_{P \in \mathcal{P}}$ such that $A = \sum_{P \in \mathcal{P}} \lambda_P P$. Then, for all $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we define $f(A) := \sum_{P \in \mathcal{P}} f\left(\lambda_P\right) P$. Note that for $f$ a polynomial function, the two definitions of $f(A)$ coincide.
The the map $eval : \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathscr{A}$ is also a a $*$-algebra morphism, therefore the image of this map contains the context generated by $A$. However, it turns out to be exactly the context generated by $A$: indeed, let $f$ be an arbitrary function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then by Lagrange's interpolation theorem, there exists a polynomial $Q$ such that for all $P$, $f\left(\lambda_P\right) = Q\left(\lambda_P\right)$. Therefore, $f(A) = Q(A)$, so $f(A)$ is a polynomial in $A$.

Now, let us consider some self-adjoint element $A$ that cannot be written as before. Then, we cannot, in general, define $f(A)$! To do this, we generally need to consider some topology on $\mathscr{A}$, write $f$ as a limit (in some sense) of polynomials, and we try to transfer the convergence of functions to the convergence of elements. For example, if $\mathscr{A}$ is endowed with a $C^*$-norm and complete, we can reach all continuous $f$'s; if $\mathscr{A}$ is a closed subset of the set of bounded operators on a Hilbert space, endowed with the weak operator topology, we can reach all Borel function $f$'s. In this cases, if you require that a context must be the smallest closed thing, you get more than polynomials of $A$ in the context generated by $A$.

Now, an example. Consider a separable Hilbert space, an orthonormal basis $(\xi_n)_n$ and the bounded operator $A$ defined by, for all $n$, $A\xi_n = \frac{1}{n} \xi_n$ if $n$ is nonzero, and $0$ if $n$ is zero. Then the operator $B$ defined by, for all $n$, by $B\xi_n=0$ if $n$ is nonzero, and $B\xi_0=\xi_0$. Then $B$ is the image of $A$ by a Borel function, but it isn’t a polynomial in $A$. Therefore, your claim is wrong.

Comment: I don't quite understood what is the problem with considering the smallest abelian sub-$*$-algebra from a $*$-algebra such that the set $\{A_n\}_{n \in I}$ is  contained in this abelian sub-$*$-algebra, a priori there could be no abelian sub-$*$-algebra that contains $\{A_n\}_{n \in I}$, but by considering the set formed by terms that are either the identity or sums of elements of $\{A_n\}_{n \in I}$ or products of elements of $\{A_n\}_{n \in I}$ or that can be written as sums between terms or products between terms, then this set is a $*$-algebra that is abelian, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. The definition is not wrong, just badly written: the set of polynomials IS the context generated.

Comment: This is somewhat frustrating, the big problem that I am trying to show using this is that I can bijectively map non zero linear functionals that are also $*$-homomorphisms to "valuation" functions $v$ such that $v(f(A))=f(v(A))$ for any operator and functional calculus of A given by $f(A)$. For finite matrix algebras this theorem can be proven so elegantly using those types of relations, as is done in pages 34-36 in https://alves-nickolas.github.io/pdf/Applications_of_Topos_Theory_to_the_Mathematical_Foundations_of_Quantum_Theory.pdf

Comment: This reference are some lecture transcripts from a friend that also saw the same minicurse on Topos theory applied to Quantum Mechanics, but since it was a minicurse only the simple case of matrix algebras was covered. Analogous statements are made in the bibliographic references but they are just kind of asserted without proof, and a analogous proof could be achieved for more general algebras if only I could prove the items (ii) and (iii) of theorem 20 in that linked pdf for more general algebras.

Comment: I did not see the word "Borel" in the pages you showed me. Can't you just write a precise mathematical question? And, for what it's worth, I suggest you read this document assuming that everything is finite-dimensional. You won't lose anything philosophically substantial, and you will avoid technical functional-analytic difficulties that are irrelevant to the subject.

Comment: These are not irrelevant, in the original paper where these notions were introduced page 13 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9803055.pdf this idea was first considered for operators with discrete spectra mapping they into their respective spectrum, in this article I understood what is going on, but when contexts were introduced in this discussion in pages 5-6 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9911020.pdf the "bijection" between valuations and multiplicative linear functionals is alluded to but not proved as is in that last proof of the first reference for the specific case of matrix algebras.

Comment: Ok, I might write another question just asking that directly then, since you did not understand what I am trying to do by requiring limited Borel measurable functions to generalise a explicit proof that was available to me for matrix algebras, even though originally the result is communicated as being more general than for those algebras.

Comment: I wrote a question directly asking what is the problem that I am having, it pertains to understand a paasge in a forementioned original paper. Here is the link to that question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4860037/is-there-actually-any-bijection-between-characters-and-global-sections-of-the-sp I would appreciate if you could read it.

Comment: I edited by answer.

Comment: Thank you that is a assertion that I did not know, so if I consider a definition of context in which there is a requirement of it being closed under the weak operator topology, then I can show that I can reach every Borel functional calculus of a operator in any such weak operator closed set, could you give me a reference for this type of assertion? That is "every Borel functional calculus of a operator $A$ is contained in a weakly operator closed set that contains $A$"?

Comment: Actually, scratch that, this containment is just a consequence of the spectral decomposition theorem (when it includes that the functional calculus commutes with every operator that commutes with the original self-adjoint) and von Neumanns bicomutant theorem.

Comment: So @Plop, if I, a fortiori, added that contexts need to be unital abelian subalgebras of the same kind of the original algebra (That is, the set of contexts of a von Neumann algebra $\mathfrak{M}$, a set contaning all abelian von Neumann subalgebra of $\mathfrak{M}$, which then already contains topological implications from the beguining) in this way I can ignore things like the unital abelian$*$-subalgebras of a $C^*$-algebra, that fail to be $C^*$-algebras themselves, or for those other cases in which structure is lost by considering subalgebras that are not of the same type as their mother

Comment: Before moving on to the other question, do you consider that this one is answered?

Comment: Is it true that the set $\{f(A) \, | \, f \text{ a limited Borel measurable function} \}$ is weakly operator closed? So as to be able to  make the second inclusion of this being within the context generated by $A$, and hence establish the equality.

Comment: Actually, from the Borel functional calculus for limited Borel measurable functions I can show that that set is strong operator closed, and from a proposition that strong operator closure implies weak operator closure for bounded operators in a Hilbert space I get that that set is weak operator closed, hence a von Neumann algebra by itself, so the opposite inclusion is true.

Comment: Ah, if you consider the smallest closed sub-algebra with respect to the weak operator topology, then you get all bounded Borel functions, yes.